# Taquito + BeaconWallet = Signer?

Tags: taquito, thanos, beacon, temple

I've configured Taquito to use the BeaconWallet this way:

```
      const wallet = new BeaconWallet(options)
      await wallet.requestPermissions({
        network: {
          type: 'edonet'
        }
      })
      this.Tezos.setProvider({ wallet })
```

It connects to the wallet. When I try to call a contract, I'm getting the error: `UnconfiguredSignerError, No signer has been configured.`. How do I set the Beacon Wallet to be the signer? I'm using the Temple Wallet browser extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using Taquito's Contract API, but the Wallet API should be used to interact with a wallet.

For example:

```
const contract = await tezos.wallet.at(contractAddress);
```

Instead of :

```
const contract = await tezos.contract.at(contractAddress);
```

More details on the wallet API here: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/wallet_API#calling-a-smart-contract

Comment: Yes, that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've come back here a few times so it's time I put the solution to my problem in case I make this mistake again:

- Check that you've actually synced your wallet

Assuming the project is in active development you may have not implemented all the necessary checks. I was doing a quick and dirty test so I missed checking for an active account.